# Google sheets - Undo action when sorting trigger is on and cell's change history

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have two problems:

1. I have sorting script that is run by trigger. When authorized user makes changes, trigger is sorting the table accordingly. But, when a user inputs a data and press ctrl+z after getting sorted by trigger, UNDO action is not working. Please advise how to solve this. P.S. trigger works under condition "On-changes"
2. Since trigger is working, all changes that are done by any users are showed as changed by "owner of the sheet", not a true user that has made that change. Please help me.

Tried to change trigger type to "on-changes", no luck. Regarding cell's history of changes - no idea at all how to solve this.

Comment: Your script is probably performs multiple processes so you may have to perform multiple cntl-z's.  If you wish help with a script you will have to provide a [mcve]